# Retrieve previous months data

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am in the process of automating some  reports and I have hit a bit of a wall attempting to automate a particular monthly report. The date/time is stored in epoch values.

Below Query:

```
SELECT
    Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4
FROM
    Table1,Table2
WHERE
    summarydate >= extract(epoch from to_timestamp('01 oct 2016', 'DD Mon YYYY'))::bigint and
    summaydate < extract(epoch from to_timestamp('01 nov 2016', 'DD Mon YYYY'))::bigint and
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 1,2
```

Currently the query is run manually after adjustments to date ranges.

With the extract from epoch in mind, is it possible to have the date changed to previous month automatically?

The goal is to set an automated report with this query to run on the first of every month for the previous months data.

I couldn't find a solution for Postgres in other questions related to 'Obtaining last month data'

Comment: I know probably is just an example, but you cant have non aggregated fields on `SELECT` if they arent in the `GROUP BY` section

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Correct It was just an example, the real select statement works within the query, I appreciate the tip though, I am still pretty novice :)

Comment: even when is a example you should try the make it the best you can, other wise we lost time with non relevant errors.  [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Gotcha, Bookmarked the page you linked for any future questions. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `DATE_TRUNC('month',DATE)` which will output the first of the month:

```
SELECT
    Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4
FROM
    Table1,Table2
WHERE
    summarydate >= extract(epoch from date_trunc('month', current_date) - interval '1 month')::bigint and
    summaydate < extract(epoch from date_trunc('month', current_date))::bigint and
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 1,2
```

Comment: perfect many thanks @sagi

I didnt think you could use interval, something for the memory bank!

Comment: No problem mate @Dante